# Nesting Variables in batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have been having a real issue getting something that seems simple, but I can not seem to get a working answer.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Setting a variable with a specific name: ex. `set "select=computer1"`
2. I do a test and give that variable a value based on the result after using an if statement : ex `set "%select%=1"` This sets the variable `%computer1%` to `1`
3. I want to see what the value of `%computer1%` is however all I know is `%select%`.

Is there any way I can get the value of `%computer1%` when only knowing `%select%`? `%select%` knows the name of the new variable but I need to know its value without being able to directly call it by hard coded name.

I thought a pipeline might work but I can not seem to figure this out.

Thanks all, I appreciate your help.

Comment: `set %select%` will output `computer1=1`

Comment: This type of management is described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), although the topic is different...

Answer (score 4):

You need another layer of parsing. You can do it:

with delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !%select%!
```

without delayed expansion:

```
call echo %%select%%
```